# Phoenix: Could not compile dependency :ranch

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, rebar3

### Background

I have created a project using `mix phx.new my_app --no-ecto` and everything looked fine. However I am not able to run the created project.

### Error

When I execute `mix phx.server` (after running `mix deps.get)`I get the following error:

```
===> Compiling ranch
===> Command ' OTP' not found in namespace bare
** (Mix) Could not compile dependency :ranch, "/home/user/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.7.3-otp-21/.mix/rebar3 bare compile --paths "/home/user/Workspace/exercises/islands_interface/_build/dev/lib/*/ebin"" command failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile ranch", update it with "mix deps.update ranch" or clean it with "mix deps.clean ranch"
```

### OS and Language Info

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco

elixir         1.7.3-otp-21
erlang         21.1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try running `mix local.rebar` and then removing `_build` and start again, just to rule out the odds of being a temporary fluke.

Comment: I have followed these instructions and the issue still persists. I have made a search online and found this rebar issue that alternates between closed and open, but I am not sure if and how this correlates to the problem I have at hand: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/4970

Comment: Hrm, which Ranch version is it trying to use? Can you try specifying this in your `mix.exs` `deps`: `{:ranch, ">= 0.0.0", manager: :make}` and see if it works?

Comment: `mix deps.get` is installing `ranch 1.7.1`. I have also followed your recommended instructions but the outcome has not changed :( .

Comment: Did you try any of these suggestions in the error? `You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile ranch", update it with "mix deps.update ranch" or clean it with "mix deps.clean ranch"`

Comment: I tried all of them, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out what the error was.

This is the absolute path of the project:

`/home/user/Workspace/Functional Web Development with Elixir, OTP, and Phoenix/islands_interface`

Turns out, `phx.server` errors out *because* it is inside the folder `/Functional Web Development with Elixir, OTP, and Phoenix/`. Turns out that space in ' OTP' in the error message is from the folder's name.

To prove my theory I created a project called `test` under `/home/user/Workspace/`. Everything worked perfectly.

Further investigation revealed the source of the problem. A Phoenix dependency, rebar3, has a bug with folders that have commas in their names.

https://elixirforum.com/t/phoenix-could-not-compile-dependency-ranch/22939/16?u=fl4m3ph03n1x